# THREE.JS : How to change object textures using looped Event listener with function?

Tags: javascript, three.js, event-handling, addeventlistener

Working on a Webgl 3D project, I want to change the textures of a loaded COLLADA object using a button for each texture

So far, **I've managed to do it** for a number of 3 textures using the same code 3 times, which leads me to the question :

How can I use a **single event listener** to change *whatever number* of textures that I have ??

***** MY CODE BELOW WORKS JUST FINE *****

here are my codes:

```html
<button type="submit" id="wd1" onclick="setMat1()" ><img src='tex/wd1.png'/></button>
<button type="submit" id="wd2" onclick="setMat2()"><img src='tex/wd3.png'/></button>
<button type="submit" id="wd3" onclick="setMat3()"><img src='tex/wd2.png'/></button>
```

And

```js
function setMat1 () {
 elf.traverse(function(child) {
 if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
     var mat1 = textureLoader.load('obj/tex/wood3.png');
     child.material.map = mat1;
 }
 elf.needsUpdate=true;
 });
 }

 function setMat2 () {
 elf.traverse(function(child) {
     if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
         var mat2 = textureLoader.load('obj/tex/wood5.png');
         child.material.map = mat2;
     }
     //elf.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
     elf.needsUpdate=true;
 });
 }
            
 function setMat3 () {
 elf.traverse(function(child) {
 if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
     var mat3 = textureLoader.load('obj/tex/wood4.png');
     child.material.map = mat3;
 }
 //elf.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
 elf.needsUpdate=true;
 });
 }
```

I asked this question here because I will add at least 20 other textures and honestly i think that it shouldn't be done the way i did it :)

Comment: I added a working example below.. let me know if you have any questions...

Comment: Any other ideas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
function setMat(matUrl) {
 new THREE.TextureLoader().load(matUrl,(tex)=>{
     scene.traverse(function(child) {
         if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
             child.material.map = tex;
             child.material.needsUpdate = true;
         }
     });
 });
}
```

-OR- an even more concise snippet below that gets the URL from the src of the image that was clicked...

```js
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var w = 300;
var h = 200;
renderer.setSize(w, h);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  45, // Field of view
  w / h, // Aspect ratio
  0.1, // Near
  10000 // Far
);
camera.position.set(15, 10, 15);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFF00);
light.position.set(20, 20, 20);
scene.add(light);
var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x808080);
light1.position.set(20, 20, 20);
scene.add(light1);
var light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0x00FFFF);
light2.position.set(-20, 20, -20);
scene.add(light2);
var light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xFF00FF);
light3.position.set(-20, -20, -20);
scene.add(light3);

var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 16, 16);
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: 0x808080
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom, material);
scene.add(mesh);
renderer.setClearColor(0xdddddd, 1);

function setMat(evt) {
  var src = evt.target.src ? evt.target.src : evt.target.children[0].src;
  new THREE.TextureLoader().load(src, (tex) => {
    scene.traverse(function(child) {
      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.material.map = tex;
        child.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });
  });
}

var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button'); 
for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++)buttons[i].onclick = setMat;
(function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  controls.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

<button><image src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xThuWg7lusylvpAVu8/giphy.gif" width=100 height=100 >1</image></button>

<button><image src="https://res.cloudinary.com/teepublic/image/private/s--gWNjhADC--/t_Preview/b_rgb:262c3a,c_limit,f_auto,h_313,q_90,w_313/v1508184648/production/designs/1977157_1" width=100 height=100 >2</image></button>

<button><image src="https://media.giphy.com/media/xThuWg7lusylvpAVu8/giphy.gif" width=100 height=100 >3</image></button></br>
```

Comment: isn't there any other way to not repeat the " onclick " attribute for the buttons ??

Comment: in your example I get an error saying that target is undefined :/

Comment: Where do you get that error? I'm not seeing it in chrome.. And yes you can install the click handler in javascript, but that's sorta outside of the scope of your original question. I posted my example because you only have to specify the URL once so I figured it fit your needs. I also assume that the click target is the image element at child[0].. for production, you would probably want to do more robust checking. I've updated the snippet to do a deeper search for the src url... does that still give you an error?

Comment: You could install the click handler in javascript by assigning a class to the button, and then in javascript, set the callback using jquery or document.getElementsByClassName(). I posted my example because you only have to specify the URL once so I figured it fit your needs. I've updated the snippet to do a deeper search for the src url... so it works both on image or button click. does that still give you an error?

Comment: Great code, it works perfectly. So from now on I'll have to define the url of the image /texture only in my HTML code right ?

- isn't there any other way to not repeat the " onclick " attribute for the buttons ??

Answer (score 0):

You just require to put the following to update the material:

```
child.material.needsUpdate = true;
child.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
```

for more example follow this link https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/materials/Material.needsUpdate

and https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/textures/Texture.needsUpdate

Comment: I am looking for a solution with an Event listener to load the function which is changing texture when i click on the buttons